# Mass field update

Tags: for-update

Some of my Accounts are known as Ultimate Parents. They are either parent or grandparent to all other Accounts for a particular company. Due to a large data migration, I would like to have the Ultimate Parent name in a field (UPName__c) on every Account. Unfortunately, this was not done when the system was initially put together, so I now must somehow put together a way to scan through all of my Accounts and get that information.

Ultimate Parent accounts have a checkbox checked to indicate they are an Ultiamte Parent (UltimateParent_*c = "Yes"). So I'm thinking I would need to query the ParentAccount*_r.UltimateParent_*c of every Account record and if the UltimateParent*_c = "Yes" then I would grab the Name field and put it into my UPName__c field.

Somehow I have to account for grandchildren accounts. Their ParentAccount will not be the Ultimate Parent, so I don't know how to obtain the Ultiamte Parent name. I'm guessing I would need to put together a query and run it a bunch of times, with the following runs checking to see if the Parent Account has UPName_*c field populated, and if it does to grab the value and put it in the current Accounts UPName*_c field...?

How would I go about doing this ? Will it be code which would be run in the developer console ?

Thank you very much for any help you can give. I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do this with a cross-object formula field, I don't think that a code-based solution is needed. The field would look up the chain of the account hierarchy for your field:

```
IF ( AND(Parent.Parent.Id  != null,Parent.Parent.UltimateParent_c = 'Yes'), Parent.Parent.Name ,
   IF (AND(Parent.Id  != null,Parent.UltimateParent_c = 'Yes'), Parent.Name , null )
)
```

Comment: would I be able to just run that code through Execute Anonymous on Eclipse and have it execute on all the Account records ?

Comment: There is no code here, this is a formula field. It will work as soon as you create the field.

Comment: Yes, I was able to figure out that I would need to do a batch update in order to accomplish this. However, my batch code isn't updating my records. I have put the code here if you would care to take a look at it. If you want to give some feedback I would appreciate it very much : 

http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17328/batch-code-execution

Thank you greenstork